# Are generating functions ever analytic for logarithmic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, generating-functions, closed-form

Given a series $s_n = \ln(n) f(n)$ where $f(\cdot)$ is an elementary analytic function which does not involve the logarithm. More precisely $f$ can have simple poles but no branch cuts or essential singularity. The generating function is then $$ g(x) = \sum_n s_n x^n $$, which seems not to simplify to a closed form expression for any $f$. For example $f(n)=1/n^3$ does not give a closed result it seems. Can anyone give a nontrivial counterexample for $f$ where the generating function gives a closed form? Are generating functions useful for these types of series?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you're asking. How about $f(z) = 1/\log z$ (with a suitable branch of $\log$ so that $f$ is analytic on the positive real axis)?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: I just wanted to note that there are other types of generating functions.  You've written the ordinary generating function of the sequence, but there are also the exponential $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and Dirichlet $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ generating functions, among others, which may be more useful.

Comment: @SpamIAm Do you know of any other common type of generating function that is useful here?

Comment: It really depends on your function $f$.  For instance, the Dirichlet generating function of $\ln(n)$ is $-\zeta'(s)$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: "$f$ can have simple poles but no branch cuts or essential singularity" - the word you're looking for is meromorphic